# Master/Detail datasets too many requests

Tags: delphi, dataset, ado

We have a Delphi application using ADO datasets in Master/Detail relationships. These connect to a SQL Server database located on another server.

The app is slow over a slow network connection due to the amount of SQL-requests the many detail datasets make when opened. Is there a way to make all the detail dataset requests in a batch?

Or is there a dataset besides ADO which could handle this situation better?

Comment: As first, this is not how master-detail related dataset objects should behave. They should query detail when master is requested. So you say that in your case all master records request details?

Comment: Did you try to use `TClientDataSet` for each table?

Comment: @Victoria First we open the master, then we open the details. Opening the detail datasets before does not make a difference. Still the same amount of requests.

Comment: One thing which works well with SqlServer + Ado is to write a stored proc which returns all the detail records for a given master.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @MartynA The detail datasets query many different tables. And are connected to different visual edit controls. Would that approach still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a while since I did this, so I no longer have access to the data which I used to benchmark it, but faced with a similar situation, the following had a huge speed improvement over standard Master/Details, for remarkably little effort.  Ymmv, of course.

Define a stored proc on the server to retrieve all the rows of all the detail datasets like this

```
create procedure GetDetails(@MasterID int) as
begin
  select * from Details1 where MasterID = @MasterID 
  select * from Details2 where MasterID = @MasterID 
  /* etc */
end
```

In the client, set up a datamodule which has an AdoStoredProc which invokes the stored proc and as many AdoDatasets as there are Detail tables.

To retrieve the rows of the Detail datasets, use code like this

```
var
  Rows : Integer;
[...]
spGetDetails.Parameters.ParamByName('@MasterID').Value := MasterID;
spGetDetails.Active := True;

Details1.RecordSet := spGetDetails.RecordSet;
Details1.Active ;= True;

Details2.RecordSet := spGetDetails.NextRecordSet(Rows);
Details2.Active ;= True;

Details3.RecordSet := spGetDetails.NextRecordSet(Rows);
Details3.Active ;= True;
  //  etc, you get the idea
```

Of course, the Details1..N AdoDataSets can be connected to standard db-aware edit controls or server as Providers to a group of TClientDataSets.

Btw, this worked particularly well where the datamodule was in the middle tier of a 3-tier setup, because I could then package up all the detail rows in a zipped stream which the dm then sent to the client.

**Update** Getting the rows of the Details tables this way seems to work fine for editing them as well as viewing them, and I can't immediately see why the Details tables wouldn't support inserts and deletes.  Each of the detail ADODatasets needs to be configured as you normally would for the detail side of an M->D, with a `CommandText` like 'select * from Detailx where MasterID = MasterID`.

Comment: Impressive! A couple of questions on this solution.
Can spGetDetails be freed after assigning the detail recordsets, without any effect on the details?
Can the details still use the methods Insert, Edit, Post, and Delete as normal?

Comment: Well, when I did it, it was purely for viewing, not editing the Details' data.  I'm not sure why you would want to free spGetDetails because then you'd need to recreate it every time the Master scrolls.  I don't think it would be too difficult to write changes made to the Details back to their tables, but would require more code than for the detail side of a usual MD.

Comment: See update to my answer.  I haven't tested inserts and deletes, but as edits to a detail row work fine, I can't immediately see why inserts and deletes wouldn't worlk also.

Comment: That’s it, thank you. I’ll be using a TADOQuery with statements separated by ; instead of a stored proc but otherwise basically the same